# Remove restriction from Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have found this bit of code from the net and I'm trying to remove the Name must be letters only and min 3 and max 20 restriction. The name entered can be less than 3 and will contain numbers. My level of JavaScript is minimal and I would really appreciate someone helping me.

```
(function($){
$.fn.checkAvailability = function(opts) {
    opts = $.extend({
        target: '#response',
        trigger: '#btnCheck',
        ajaxSource: 'test.asp',
        fireOnKeypress: true
    }, opts || {});

    var $this = $(this);

    if (opts.fireOnKeypress) {
        $this.keyup(function() {
            checkUsername();
        });

        $this.keypress(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    };

    $(opts.trigger).click(function() {
        checkUsername();
    });

    function checkUsername() {
        if (validateUsername()) {
            $(opts.target).html('<img src="loading.gif"> checking availability...');
            usernameLookup(); 
        }
        else
        {
            $(opts.target).html('Name must be letters only and min 3 and max 20');
        }   
    };

    function usernameLookup() { 
        var val = $this.val();
        $.ajax({ 
                url: opts.ajaxSource, 
                data: {fn:val,s:Math.random()},
                success: function(html){
                    $(opts.target).html(html);
                },
                error:function (){
                    $(opts.target).html('Sorry, but there was an error loading the document.');
                }
        }); 
    };

    function validateUsername(str) {
        return (/^[A-Za-z]{3,20}$/.test($this.val()));
    };
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Quick and dirty: return literal `true` from `validateUsername`. In general, it's a very bad idea to copy-paste some code from the net without fully understanding it.

Comment: So you means to say you want to remove minimum 3 characters validations and allows to number in name right?

Comment: Can you give some sample data because this regexp controls what is returned /^[A-Za-z]{3,20}$/. If you want letters and numbers between 3 and 30 characters then use /^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}$/

Comment: Did any of the given answers provide a solution for you? if so please feel free to mark them as such and give a upvote to the people who take the effort to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current implementation of `validateUsername()` uses this regex to validate user:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{3,20}$/
```

`[A-Za-z]` is the restriction "letters only";

`{3,20}` after it is the restriction "length 3 to 20". It's just saying to match a pattern preceding it if it repeats 3 to 20 characters in a row.

`^` and `$` mark string start and end respectively. these are good restrictions for validating a user name as it makes regex match entire string and not just part of it somewhere in the middle.

If you want to allow letters and digits, you can replace `[A-Za-z]` with `\w` (which is just a shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9]`).

To change length restriction just change numbers in `{3,20}`.

"Allow user names with letters, digits and no longer as 20 characters would look like this:

```
/^\w{,20}$/
```

This would match empty string as well, so I recommend using `{1,20}`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the function `validateUsername` as:

```
function validateUsername(str) {
    return (/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}$/.test($this.val()));
};
```

This will allow numbers in the name and a length between 1 and 20.
You can check the allowed values for the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/8yoBGs/1/

I recommend against removing the validation altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the `checkUsername()` and `validateUsername()` references if you don't want any username validation at all:

```
(function($){
$.fn.checkAvailability = function(opts) {
    opts = $.extend({
        target: '#response',
        trigger: '#btnCheck',
        ajaxSource: 'test.asp',
        fireOnKeypress: true
    }, opts || {});

    var $this = $(this);

    function usernameLookup() { 
        var val = $this.val();
        $.ajax({ 
                url: opts.ajaxSource, 
                data: {fn:val,s:Math.random()},
                success: function(html){
                    $(opts.target).html(html);
                },
                error:function (){
                    $(opts.target).html('Sorry, but there was an error loading the document.');
                }
        }); 
    };

};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateUsername(str) {
        return (/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}$/.test($this.val()));
    };
```

Now it can accept numbers all allow usernames with 1+ length

Answer (score 0):

Generally, name allows Characters and numbers so I keep validation as it is but allows number and there are minimum one characters allows if it compulsory otherwise you may remove it from your code also.

```
function checkUsername() {
    if (validateUsername()) {
        $(opts.target).html('<img src="loading.gif"> checking availability...');
    }
    else
    {
        $(opts.target).html('Name must be letters or number only');
    }   
};

 function validateUsername(str) {
    return (/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}$/.test($this.val()));
 };
```

otherwise, if you don't want to put any validation then

```
function checkUsername() {
    if (validateUsername()) {
        // Do whatever your want to do.
    } 
};

 function validateUsername(str) {
    return true;
 };
```